# Using only FCM Token to send Google Cloud Messaging Push Notifications in React Native?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've inherited a React Native app that at one time did send push notifications via Cloud Messaging in Firebase. I've read the docs, and I know what direction I need to go in order to create a push notification service, so that isn't really where my question lies.

I don't see anywhere in my app that we are accepting incoming push notifications. There is one instance that is setup that will send a push notification that is very specific, however, I am still able to create a test notification and target my test Android device with it's FCM and I receive the notification fine. Unfortunately, our teams are segmented and I have no access to the backend to check if we have logic there, but upon reading some documentation and articles, it seems that this case ***might*** be true:

If the app gets a token from `messaging().getToken()` this registers that device in Firebase, and when using the Admin console to create a notification and I chose Android as the target, it would send that push notification to every Android device in that application with an FCM token. Is there really no other code needed for this use case? Is this just the Android translation layer doing its thing and it's really that simple? I've been banging my head against the wall trying to find where we have this logic in our application and I'm coming up empty.

My fear is that I'm missing something and when I begin to build out the new push notification integrations, some users may get double notifications if I'm not tracking down how the initial one is working in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app is not actively being used, incoming notifications are displayed automatically by the system. You indeed have to write no specific code for this use-case.

There are quite some potential other steps you may want to take though, so I recommend having a look at the documentation on [setting up an Android client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) for use with Firebase Cloud Messaging.